# How to loop over json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Iam having a Json object in the below format

```
var obj={"results": [{"division": "xxx", "xxx": "Administration", "id": "0001", "designation": "Chief Managing Director", "name": "Dr. xxx xx xx"}]};
```

when am looping over this json by using

```
for (var i in obj.results){
}
```

when am  debugging it is giving me obj.results is undefined.

Please help

Comment: Missing curly brace now

Comment: Note: If it's inside code and not in a string, then it's a [JavaScript Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals). Though JSON shares some of the syntax, they are separate languages used for different purposes.

Comment: Ok i think you made this mistake while posting question here. can you update?

Comment: @Amit Joki sorry guys no mistake in braces its just a typo..please see my edits

Comment: With the edit, the problem would appear to be elsewhere or in combination with something else: http://jsfiddle.net/WY6Pb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var obj = { "results": [{ "division": "xxx", "xxx": "Administration", "id": "0001", "designation": "Chief Managing Director", "name": "Dr. xxx xx xx"}] };

        for (var i in obj.results) {
        }
```

Its working

Answer (score 0):

Note that, `obj.results` isn't an array.

I think you are needing this:

```
for(var i in Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj.results)){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here your json is not in correct format. you are missing closing braces. It should be like this :

```
var obj={"results": [{"division": "xxx", "xxx": "Administration", "id": "0001", "designation": "Chief Managing Director", "name": "Dr. xxx xx xx"}]}
```

Then your for loop will work properly.

```
for (var i in obj.results){
}
```